# How does the iPhone photo's app load so many images so quickly and smoothly?

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, uiimage

I'm building an application that requires a bunch of local images to be displayed in the imageview of a uitableviewcell. However, i'm having difficulty optimizing the performance of the uitableview. I've noticed two issues specifically: first, the view takes a while to load. Second, the scrolling gets laggy when new cells are displayed.

The viewDidLoad is loading in the images like this:

```
for (Object *object in self.objects)
{
    object.thumbnail = [UIImage imageNamed:object.imageName];
}
```

this is obviously causing the long-load issue, but I'm not sure how else to get those images loaded. Is it a size issue? is this just a bad way of doing it?

The process of displaying the images also seems to be problematic, in other words, even after the images have been assigned to the thumbnail property, they still take too long to be drawn.

Although this is a specific case, I'm curious more generally on how apple loads images in photos so efficiently. Any insights? thanks

Comment: They probably also cache the thumbnail at the proper size so that it doesn't have to be created from the full image every time.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I find that my UI is lagging, the first thing I suspect is that I am performing some operation synchronously (on the main thread) that should be performed asynchronously (on a background thread).

I am also very curious as to how exactly Apple is achieving that performance in the photo app.  I am writing an app that has similar requirements as yours right now.  My current approach is to load a bunch of photos from disk into memory asynchronously as soon as the user opens my view controller, and continue to load (and remove photos) from memory - ahead of time - as the user scrolls.

Currently, I load each photo from disk asynchronously in cell for row at index path, which is pretty fast, but causes this cascading effect to happen if you scroll quickly through the table view.  That is, the cell will appear empty for a moment before the photo appears.

I hope this sheds some light for you.

You may also be interested in trying SDWebImage - which includes an image cache object that has been making my life easier when dealing with local photos.

Answer (score 0):

They are doing everything in the background on various detached threads most likely. This will allow for a great deal of fluidity in applications that are hosting/presenting a great deal of information. I have created a photo gallery myself in various applications, loading many photos simultaneously from different web APIs and whatnot, and by simply creating new threads and managing the allocation efficiently and accurately, you can get a very smooth interface/interaction

Answer (score 0):

Well, the long-load issue is caused by this part of your code - `UIImage imageNamed:`, because this method caches all the images on the same thread, and also could crash the app if the memory is overloaded.

Try looking at this library - it should do what you are trying to achieve :)
http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ktphotobrowser